# Authenticate using Google OAuth2 and Postman

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, postman, google-oauth

Like a week or two ago I used to authenticate in Postman using Google OAuth2 with no problem.
But I believe that Google has changed something, because right now it doesn't take me straight to the result of authentication (which is a redirection to my django backend) with access and refresh tokens in response.
But right now it looks like some kind of DDoS prevention redirection and in Postman I got an HTML with the script below, that is not being run (most likely Postman is not running it - thus not forwarding).

```
<script type="text/javascript" nonce="H3VTxxxx1x1Ixxxx/Dr/ng">
    xsrfstatemanager.chooseKeyAndRedirect( 'https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/signin\/oauth?client_id\x3d2305xxxx9382-bs4v9fkxxxxnt53cf4skirxxxxkmkj4l.apps.googleusercontent.com\x26as\x3dF-fPfkixxxxyJIIdgxxxxw\x26destination\x3dhttp:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\x26approval_state\x3d!ChQ4dExxxxUzbndIRxxxxkJZU2UzOBIfWXd1LxxxxDVmT3NkOERFdWhZOThQxxxxdWFSQTVoWQ%E2%88%99AJDr988AAAxxxx0ayvP61bbERtYdABfULE34-qRLGgUd\x26oauthgdpr\x3d1\x26xsrfsig\x3dChkAeAxxxxp2XLUCh0OhQv7fnFihxzJthXPzEg5hcHByb3xxxxzdGF0ZRILZGVzdGluYXRpb2xxxxNvYWN1Eg9vYXV0aHJpcxxxx2NvcGU', 'wHNxxxxQ2EVRv5apbGxxxxLjbgegn_BxxxxoHJxA-2g', 'OCAK',true,true, 'https:\/\/accounts.google.com\/o\/nocookie');
</script>
```

It works fine in browser, as JS is being run and is actually forwarding it.
What can I do to make it work in Postman?